# Declaration in .h. Definition in .cpp. Correct?

Tags: c++, global-variables, declaration, definition

It's incredible.  Over 30 years I've been programming and I seem to have forgotten how to handle global variables.  (It's because I never really use them I guess.)  In the header file I have -

```
// any.h
bool neat;
```

and in the cpp -

```
// any.cpp
#include <any.h>
bool neat = false;
```

it told me I was redefining.  So I took out the 'bool' -

```
// any.cpp
#include <any.h>
neat = false;
```

Now it tells me "**error: ‘neat’ does not name a type**"
How can it not know 'neat' is a bool?  It's the same translation unit 
so I don't need an **extern**.  I haven't declared anything **static** 
so I know there is no limitation to file scope.  This is supposed to be 
a global variable.

My understanding of the difference between declaring and defining is 
that with 'declaring' you are just informing the compiler a name is 
of a certain type.  Whereas with 'defining' the compiler actually sets 
aside some space in the executable for the name to exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `bool neat;` actually defines the variable neat, it just doesn't initialize it.

Comment: *I never really use them I guess* Please stick to it if you can. It will be better to use `bool getNeat();` and `void setNeat(bool);` than using a global variable.

Comment: @RSahu - Do you mean as functions within a class (or namespace)?  Or do you mean as global functions?  And if so, how is that better to have two global names (setNeat and getNeat) instead of one (neat) ?

Comment: @Clive, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `extern` keyword in your header file (and keep the `bool` in your .c file)

```c
// any.h
extern bool neat;

// any.cpp
#include <any.h>
bool neat = false;
```

The reason to do that is to let the linker know there is a variable of that name anywhere in any object, but not reserve memory for it in every object using that variable. However, in the object actually defining the variable, you have to define it as you would do it for a non exported variable.

Comment: Are you saying that the `extern` keyword does not just affect the linker?  But also tells the compiler not to treat it as a definition?

Comment: @Clive Yes. It's telling the compiler that the variable is defined somewhere else.

Comment: Correct, in the end, it's necessary for the linker, of cource it is parsed by the syntax parser and then compiled (with or without memory reservation) by the compiler

Comment: OK.  Thank you both @Psi and songyuanyao.   It seems that the **extern** keyword is needed to tell the compiler it's only a declaration.  Is this only true for simple variables at global scope?  I mean, function prototypes you customarily put in header files _without the extern keyword_.

Comment: OK.  Thank you both Psi and @songyuanyao.   It seems that the **extern** keyword is needed to tell the compiler it's only a declaration.  Is this only true for simple variables at global scope?  I mean, function prototypes you customarily put in header files _without the extern keyword_.

Comment: @Clive Functions don't need `extern` for this case; their declaration doesn't contain a function body, the definition does. That won't change with `extern` or not.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `bool neat;` (and `bool neat = false;`) is a [definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition); That means if you put them both in the header file and implementatioin file, you'll get multiple definition error.

You could use [extern](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) to change it a declaration,

> In addition, a variable declaration that uses extern and has no initializer is not a definition.

e.g. you can declare them in header file as

```
extern bool neat; // declaratioin
```

and define them in implementation file as

```
bool neat;        // definition
                  // or bool neat = false; same effect here
```

About the error of the 2nd code snippet, note `neat = false;` is not declaration nor definition; it's a statement (assignment), which must be put in a function. e.g.

```
// any.h
bool neat; // definition

// any.cpp
#include <any.h>
void init_neat() { 
    neat = false;
}
int main() {
    init_neat();
    // use neat ...
}
```

Comment: "extern" ???   Really?   extern is for the linker to connect two separate translation units with knowing the same symbol refers to the same memory.  I have just one compilation.

Comment: No the default directories are such that it picks up <any.h>.  If it didn't it would complain of an absent file.

Comment: @Clive If you have only one translation unit, i.e. only compile `any.cpp`, then put `bool neat;` in `any.h` or `any.cpp` would be fine.

Comment: songyuanyao:  Well I put bool neat; in any.h, but I need to give it a starting value.  And I though "= false" would have to go in the cpp.

Comment: @Clive You can put `bool neat;` in `any.h` and put `neat = false;` in `any.cpp`. BTW: Even you don't initialize it, the default initialized value for `neat` will be `false`.

Comment: Well I did that. (the last thing you suggested)  But it said   **error: ‘neat’ does not name a type**.  That's what I can't understand.  If the compiler reads the .h and then the .cpp (or rather - reads a bit of the .cpp then includes in the .h) then it should know the type of 'neat'.  All I can think is that - globally - it only looks for type statements.

Comment: @Clive I got it. Note that `neat = false;` is a statement, which must be put in function.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said:

> Do you mean as functions within a class (or namespace)? Or do you mean as global functions? And if so, how is that better to have two global names (setNeat and getNeat) instead of one (neat) ?

It is less important whether the function is in a namespace or it is a global function. IMO, it is better to provide access to the data through a function than accessing it through a global variable.

You have various options in the implementation of the functions.

1. You can use a variable to maintain the state.
2. You can pass the function call to another function whose implementation maintains the state.
3. You can use an aggregate object, like a `struct`, to maintain many other global states of the application.

You give yourself the option of being able to change how and where the data is maintained when you provide access to it through a function.

Comment: @R Sahu.  Sorry, I disagree.  You are forgetting that 'neat' is just a boolean variable.  'Set' and 'get' functions provide nothing extra.  Knowing OO, I am well aware that functions provide a means to make sure the state of an object is good; and constructors especially that an object starts off in an acceptable state.  However a boolean has only two states, so they don't help anything.

Comment: @Clive, I am not forgetting that `neat` is just a boolean variable. I find it easier to deal with global data behind functional interfaces. It makes maintenance easier in the long run. I am not sure what sort of project you are working on. It might good enough to use a global variable for your needs.